# Why css cannot style the <div> element with <img> element to conrtrol the size of image using css?

Tags: html, css

I have saved my changes then to it does not work.
The css code is not able to control the size of div.img element.
Is it that I have to apply css style on img element itself?
actually even after the corrections m not able to get desired output i.e I am not able to style a image in div element using css

[**Html**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Trrm.jpg)

**[Css code**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2CB1.jpg)

Comment: Please post code as text; images aren't copy-pasteable, and SO already has syntax highlighting anyways.

Comment: You **haven't** saved your html file! have you?

Answer (score 2):

usage of css is wrong (div.img) instead use

```
div img{
  insert styles here
}
```

Comment: and img tag has not closing tag......... <img src="png.png"/>

Comment: go through w3 school tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/css/